# Custom call-in progress status bar over home page

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, statusbar

I am try to implement call in progress bar like wats-app call in IOS (as shown in image). The progress bar need to hover the home screen while application goes in background.

[image: Call in progress image]

Please advice

Thanks

Amith

Answer (score 0):

This bar will show up automatically when your app is working in background mode.
The color will between red and blue depending on the background task you are performing.
Note: Some background modes doesn't show this bar (like audio playback for example).

Comment: How can we customise , can you provide some code snippet

Comment: You can't customize them. iOS decides to show them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Goto to project -> target -> capabilities
Select "Background Modes" check Voice over ip if you want to implement call like whatsapp and need a progress bar